# Searching by a Sequence Numbers would be faster than searching a string?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I'm running a site, and I have 4.5 millions of documents in my collection. I need to add another field for any document, there would be like 10 different string at all those 4.5 million. 
The string would be like "Apache 2.0 Using E".

I need to find all the documents, have, for example, in this field "Apache 2.0 Using E". So should I search by this string, or should I create another collection for all the strings, and than in my 4.5 mil collection search by IDs of the field? Sure I would use Indexes, but is searching by a Sequence Numbers would be faster than searching a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, searching for numeric equality will probably be faster than a string comparison, helped also because the size of the documents searched will be smaller.  It's hard to say though whether the speed increase will be significant, since the performance will be impacted by a number of factors that might dwarf a string vs integer comparison - for example how the size increase of the documents affects what's in RAM, or whether doing another query for the string each request is slower.

Indexes will be *much* faster.